# Convert cell to blank based on time condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(123L, 123L), Disease_Name = c("Heart Disease", 
"Lung Disease"), Disease_start = c("4/11/17", "4/11/17"), Procedure_start = c("4/11/18", 
"4/11/16")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I want to restructure the dataframe so that:

- If the `Disease_start` is BEFORE `Procedure_start`, then convert `Disease_Name` to a blank/NA cell
- If the `Disease_start` is AFTER `Procedure_start`, then leave `Disease_Name` (don't change anything)

The output dataset should look like this:

```
> dput(df2)
structure(list(Person_ID = c(123L, 123L), Disease_Name = c("", 
"Lung Disease"), Disease_start = c("4/11/17", "4/11/17"), Procedure_start = c("4/11/18", 
"4/11/16")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Disease_Name = case_when(Disease_start < Procedure_start ~"", 
      TRUE ~ Disease_Name))
```

-output

```
  Person_ID Disease_Name Disease_start Procedure_start
1       123                    4/11/17         4/11/18
2       123 Lung Disease       4/11/17         4/11/16
```

Comment: Quick follow up question--is it possible to modify the code you gave me to make if the cell blank if the `Disease_start` is less than one day before the `Procedure_start`?

Comment: @Jamie For that you may have to convert to `Date` class first i.e. `library(lubridate);df %>% mutate(across(c(Disease_start, Produced_start), dmy)) %>% mutate(Disease_Name = case_when((Procedure_start -Disease_start) == 1  ~"", 
      TRUE ~ Disease_Name))